# decomposing a list of points in drRacket

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a list of points with the form :

```
((1.10) (2.980) (3.567) (4.0)...(1000.87 ))
```

And, to be able to use them in the function plot, I would like to extract the two sublist with the x and the y separated. So I want to have that :

x :  `(1 2 3 4 ... 1000)`

and

y : `(10 980 567 0 ... 87)`

For the first one I just use `(define x ( build-list 1000 (lambda (x) (+ x 1 )))`
But for the second one I don't find any function to help me :(

I guess i could make a procedure with a loop that use car and cdr but I am a newbee in racket and I can't do a simple loop (I really miss the simple for and while of the other language)
So does anyone know a already made fonction that could solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your list is made up of decimals, rather than dotted pairs, as I think you want. So it should have spaces between the numbers and the dots. However, that's a minor issue.

For your main question, the simplest thing is probably to map "car" and "cdr" onto your list separately:

```
(define list-of-points '((1 . 10) (2 . 980) (3 . 567) (4 . 0) ... (1000 . 87)))
(define x (map car list-of-points))
(define y (map cdr list-of-points))
```

Check out the [documentation on map](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html) for more information.

Comment: Oh, map is a great fonction, tank you ^^